# Fortran 95: open statement, status variable: unknown vs. replace

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran95

I would like to know what is the different between this statement:

`open(unit=11,file="something.TXT",status="unknown")`, which is Fortran's default `status` (i.e., the previous statement is the same as `open(unit=11,file="something.TXT"`)

and this statement:

`open(unit=11,file="something.TXT",status="replace")`

I have the impression that the `unknown` status behave exactly as I would expect with `replace`: if the file doesn't exist, it creates it. If it does exist, then it replaces it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Fortran standard lays down that the interpretation of `status='unknown'` is processor-dependent.  That is, your impression is subtly incorrect.

In the draft of the 1995 standard I have at hand this is explained in section 9.3.4.2.

In the draft of the 2003 standard I have at hand this is explained in section 9.4.5.15.

Comment: What exactly processor-dependency means? But regardless of that, this then implies that in order to maximize portability, I must absolutely always assign a value to `status` when opening a file?

Comment: You got it right.  Processor-dependent means that your compiler / run-time get to make the choice for you, if you want to be sure of the behaviour of the `open` statement you have to specify one of the other options for `status=`.